# Opening a folder from web application using C# giving access denied

Tags: c#, windows-8, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7.5

I have used the following code to open the folder from the server on my screen through ASP.Net MVC 5.0 web application hosted on IIS 7.5 on the same server, server is using windows 8.

```
public void OpenFolder()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo() {
        FileName = "\\SERVERNAME\Public\Lists",
        UseShellExecute = true,
        Verb = "open"
    }); 
}
```

This is opening the folder fine when I am running my application in development, Whereas giving Access denied error when in production.

I have given all permissions to IUSR and IIS_IUSRS to the folder along with Administrators, Users, Network, Network service and few other users. But still no luck.

If somebody has faced the same problem before or know how to resolve the issue then please throw some light and guide me to the way. Also, I am not good at networking side.

Comment: Try running as Admin

Comment: @Dave I have the admin privilages, what should I run as Admin, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Is the folder you are trying to open on the same machine as your application?

Comment: Also is the folder being used by any other application or process?

Comment: Yes, both are on same machine

Comment: No, not used by any other app or process

Comment: How are you currently starting your application?

Comment: @Learner Being on the same machine won't help (AIUI) because it will be treated as a network resource, because that is how it is specified).

Comment: In browser through IIS

Comment: Really?? that's strange, So you mean if the folder is located on different server but in the same network will do the trick

Answer (score 5):

In development (using something like IIS Express) the process running your code runs as your login account.

But once deployed it will run as whatever account the IIS application pool is configured as.

Note also that IUSR etc. are *local* accounts; this will be treated as guest when connecting to network resources (like a share). For that you'll need to run the application pool as a domain account (or local account on both machines with matching username and password).

Comment: @Ricard, how about if I give access Permissions to guests??

Comment: @Learner It's more secure to use an account adhoc with the explicit permissions to do this. Guest account could be used for other scenarios where those permissions might not be desired

Comment: @Learner as Oscar notes, that would given everyone (guest: no password) access. You need to either have everything locally and use app pool identity, or create the necessary user accounts.

Comment: @Ricard thanks, but even after given access to Guests, I am still facing the same problem

Comment: @Ricard, now I have used custom account in Application pool and given access to the folder with the same account, this time I got Server execution failed error

Comment: @Learner You're going to have to debug. Checking the identity of the server process and the login identity for the network usage would be a start (and this is why I have login/logoff auditing enabled in Windows).

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the app pool identity (IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool - replace DefaultAppPool with the name of your app pool if different) permissions on the folder. See this link- 
http://devonenote.com/2010/09/grant-permission-to-defaultapppool-identity/